# IIS 6 SMTP service stops working after server restart

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, smtp, iis-6

I'm currently wrestling with IIS6 SMTP service not working properly when the server is restarted. This has only just started happening in the last month and struggling to pin point the issue. I thought it was a failed windows update, but I've since fixed that and upon restart, the issue remains.

The service is set to automatic and recovery options are in place to start it back up.

After a restart, both Services and IIS6 Manager show the service has started, but no emails are processed from the queue directory until I restart the service (not start and stop) via services.msc.

I've scoured event logs and there isn't anything in there about failing to start smtpsvc or other errors. I'm at a real loss why this has just started to happen.

Am I missing something? Are there any other areas I should be looking into?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing in the system or app logs?

Comment: Nothing. Just the normal delivery failures to specific email domains. Nothing application level :/